# how to implement single instance of web application

Tags: web-applications, tomcat, java

I want to run only one instance of my web-application which is deployed in tomcat 5.5 how to implement it.

for example if the system has 2 tomcat server each having the web application name xxx i don't want the two application run in parallel only one should run at a time.

suppose if the user access the index.jsp inside tomcat 1 and after that when he try to access the index.jsp from tomcat 2 it should n't happen

Comment: what exactly do you mean by single instance? Do you want to create a singleton inside your web application or do you just want to create a web application and deploy it once?

Comment: restrict the application from copying to the other tomcat server and accessing it

Answer (score 0):

Here is one `workaround` way of doing it (assuming both Tomcat instances are on same host):

- Deploy webapp from its own path using docBase parameter rather than copying it physically under individual `webapp` directory of both Tomcats
- In your servlet's `contextInitialized` method start a [ServerSocket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) on particular port eg: 5555
- If you cannot start ServerSocket and it throws exception then catch that exception and re-throw a RuntimeException from the same contextInitialized method.

This way once you start first instance of the application it will start listening on that port `5555`. Now when you start 2nd instance it obviously cannot acquire port `5555` since it is already in use and will result in RuntimeException, which in turn will cause Tomcat to ** not to deploy** 2nd instance of same webapp.